# How to extract the session object from a session id?

Tags: java, servlets

In a servlet , I can get the session associated with one browser from httpRequest. I have one more sessionId say ID2(associated with another browser) in this request.

My question is how I can get the session object associated with ID2 from the same request?

Basically I want to extract the session object from a session id. As per my understanding here should be session map stored some where in server which I can use here?

The need for one more session id in request is a different story which I don't want to mention here, to avoid confusion.

Comment: "_to avoid confusion_": I'm afraid that is too late. If you have two sessionIds associated with the request, then you must have added the second sessionId in a way that should allow you to retrieve it in the reverse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using pure servlets without any other technologies like the JSF or Struts, 
AFAIK there is no direct method you can get the sessions created.
I would recommend you to implement the `sessionListener` and maintain a list of sessions yourself.